# Wrong results in query with ORDER BY and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I have a problem with a query generated by an ORM framework to limit and order the results in the Oracle Database 11.2.0.1.0    64bit Production. The generated select looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT this_.*
   FROM plate this_
   WHERE this_.id IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT this_.id AS y0_ FROM plate this_ )
   ORDER BY this_.name asc)
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Trying to understand the problem I created the following sandbox:

```
create table plate ( id integer primary key, 
                    name varchar2(30), 
                    description varchar2(255) );

insert into plate values ( 1, 'AAA-1234', 'test1' );
insert into plate values ( 2, 'BBB-1234', 'test2' );
insert into plate values ( 3, 'CCC-1234', 'test3' );
insert into plate values ( 4, 'DDD-1234', 'test4' );
commit;
```

Executing the select in this example it returns:

```
id  name        description
1   DDD-1234    (null)
2   DDD-1234    (null)
3   DDD-1234    (null)
4   DDD-1234    (null)
```

In my understanding it should return:

```
id  name        description
1   AAA-1234    test1
2   BBB-1234    test2
3   CCC-1234    test3
4   DDD-1234    test4
```

What is wrong? Why is it not returning what I expected it to?

**Edited:**
Removing the ORDER BY clause it returns the expected result. But why?

**Edited 2:**
The execution plan is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |       |       |       |     4 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                  |       |     4 |   636 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|       |     4 |   636 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | PLATE |     4 |   636 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=10)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: For me the query returns all the four distinct values of PLATES table. There's no error here. It should be said that the query has redundant piece: "id IN (SELECT DISTINCT this_.id AS y0_ FROM plate this_ )" which does nothing in this case.

Comment: It seems some kind of bug in CBO, causing a wrong re-writing of your query. Just tested in 11.2.0.2.0 XE, it works well. If you could post the execution plan, it would be useful.

Comment: @Aleksej Execution plan added on the question.

Comment: Tried on 10.2.0.4.0, 11.2.0.2.0, 11.2.0.3.0, same plan as your, but right result. Could not try on 11.2.0.1.0. Sorry, no ideas, let's see if someone with more experience can help.

Answer (score 1):

In the subquery, there is something that seems strange to me:

```
SELECT this_.* FROM plate **this_**
WHERE this_.id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT this_.id AS y0_ FROM plate **this_** )
ORDER BY this_.name asc
```

The this_ alias is used twice for 2 different Selects. Maybe this causes something wrong with the results.
I am not sure what this_ is pointing to in the order by clause for example.
I cannot guarantee this is the reason for your issue but it seems very odd to me.

Comment: Even if I change the query to `SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.* FROM plate t1 WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id AS y0_ FROM plate t2 ) ORDER BY t1.name ) WHERE rownum <= 10;` the result is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting... I found it is the combination of these three elements that causes the wrong results:

1. `WHERE this_.id IN (SELECT...)`
2. `ORDER BY` as you pointed out in your Edit
3. `ROWNUM` in the outer select

If you omit one of the three elements listed here above everything is ok. Don't know what confuses Oracle. To maintain the structure of your query I'd use ROW_NUMBER() in the subquery instead of ROWNUM in the outer Select. This way:

```
SELECT id, name, description
FROM
    (SELECT this_.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY this_.name ASC) AS RN
     FROM plate this_
     WHERE this_.id IN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT this_.id AS y0_ FROM plate this_ )
    )
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY rn asc;
```

Comment: Nice solution, gives the right result, but it is somewhat dificult to make the ORM generate this kind of query (The ORM generate the `rownum` part automatically to limit the number of results).

Comment: @Willian Well, if you cannot change the SQL generated by the ORM, I see only two options: (1) convince the ORM to generate a better SQL (element 1 in my list here above `where this_.id in (select...` is useless or (2) convince Oracle to fix what seems a bug... Good luck :-)